# How ribs angle change wing overall shape?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing-sweep

How ribs angle change wing overall shape?

Comment: 20 edits, and the question is now unintelligible. VTC as needing more detail.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the rigidity of the upper and lower skins.

As far as large jets go, you see different variations; ribs parallel to the airflow, ribs perpendicular to one of the spars, ribs perpendicular to mean chord.  In the 737 cutaway below, they appear to be more or less perpendicular to the rear spar.

Aerodynamically it's not important on large swept wing aircraft, since the ribs' orientation doesn't impact the outer contour of the airfoil, because the upper and lower skins are very heavy and stiff and are effectively the spar caps (the primary tension and compression members of a box beam), and the "spars" are really just bulkheads closing the box at the front and back, with the ribs supporting the box. So whether you angle the rib this way or that doesn't make much difference and it comes mostly down to ease of manufacture.

On the other hand, if you have a swept fabric covered wing, or a metal wing with thin skins that can bulge between the ribs, then it could be an issue and ideally you'd want the ribs to be parallel to the local air stream (which may vary a bit from the free stream) as much as possible to minimize air flow "across the bulges" so to speak.  But if the upper and lower skins are stiff enough to retain their contour between the ribs, it makes no difference and you can orient the ribs in a way that makes it easiest to build the wing, with the rib contour shaped to accommodate the orientation in achieving the overall airfoil shape.

[image]

Comment: That's why my last sentence "with the rib contour shaped to accommodate the orientation in achieving the overall airfoil shape".  Basically, a perpendicular rib turned to be parallel to the airflow needs to be stretched.  My point is that if the skins are stiff enough to not deform between the ribs, the orientation doesn't matter aerodynamically, just the shape adjusted to fit the required profile.

Comment: Same thing. If the skins are stiff enough not to deform from air loads, bulge in on the bottom and out on the top, the angle of the ribs doesn't matter.  If they are parallel to mean chord, the profile would be shorter than if they were turned to be parallel to airflow. The ribs on the left would be a bit shorter than the ribs on the right to get the same overall wing shape. You can make the skins stiff enough you don't need ANY ribs if you want.  The Rutan composite airplanes like the Long Eze have no internal ribs, just a core of solid foam wrapped with a fiberglass skin, like a surfboard.

Comment: You are thinking I'm turning the rib from this orientation to that orientation without changing its shape.If I build the rib to the airfoil profile on a swept wing, where it is a slice of the wing along the longitudinal axis, the rib profile is the airfoil profile.If I design the rib to be perpendicular to the rear spar like the 737 pictured,the rib curvature will be shortened but its curvature will be such that the SAME airfoil profile is being maintained and if I saw thru that wing on the long axis, the proper (longer) airfoil profile is there. As I said, this won't work with flexible skins.

Comment: Yes I did.  Reread my last sentence in the post.  On battens, I would say its because the air velocities relative to chord (Reynolds number) involved are too low to matter, and in the absence of a rigid trailing edge, you have to put them in a fan pattern for them to work in producing the right overall shape, but there are those here with fluid dynamics expertise that would be better positioned to answer in detail.

Comment: Yes this is a problem with a flexible skin.

Comment: I don't think the low air velocities make it worthwhile.

Answer (score 4):

In aerodynamic theory, airfoil sections are always defined parallel to the plane orthogonal to the yaw axis, effectively the direction of the oncoming airflow.

For example in the case of a swing-wing, its airfoil section is considered to vary as the wing changes sweep, from a short airfoil at minimum sweep to a long airfoil at maximum sweep. Yaw will change the apparent length of the airfoil just like varying sweep.

A swept, twisted or otherwise varying wing will create varying sideways flows which may zigzag over the surface. But the airfoil is never defined to follow any such path. This is partly because the paths over the upper and lower surfaces may differ markedly and the idea of a definite airfoil section becomes meaningless.

Engineers do things differently. The wing ribs may be skewed diagonally for mechanical reasons, and they are carefully made to be different from the true aerodynamic airfoil. An engineer might describe them as airfoils because the look and function mechanically in much the same way, but his aerodynamic colleague would probably disagree.

In the case of a swept wing with rigid skin, it is easiest to set the ribs at right angles to the main spar, so this is what engineers usually do. Of course, the ribs will be shortened so that the true airfoil in the direction of travel will be the right length.

Comment: No, not at all. Most wings have hard skins which completely hide the ribs underneath, some have no ribs underneath. You haver just made the question not fit the answers or comments any more. Please undo your change. If you want to ask a different question, ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Shape-wise, modern aircraft optimize their wing shape with 3D CFD, and do not have constant airfoil sections. Every rib (per side) is unique in profile.

Structurally, the ribs carry very little load, and are not important to the overall strength of the wing. It's the spars that carry the serious loads. The ribs just hold up the shape.

As such, the default direction for the actual ribs is the shortest line between the leading edge and the trailing edge. It will vary depending on component placement convenience.

Comment: @NoahPrandtl The answer says to consider both edges, which might not necessarily be parallel, not only the leading one.